# Deploying to FIREBASE - Error: There was an error deploying functions

Tags: firebase, npm, google-cloud-platform, deployment

I was looking to test a function but getting this error. Am I missing anything? Can anyone help me?

This is the error message in my terminal:

```
firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'procuradoria-15967'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...      
i  functions: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (52.22 KB) for uploading
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 12 function testeadm(us-central1)...

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        testeadm(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

This is my Index.js:

```
// Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
const { initializeApp } = require("firebase-admin/app")
const { getFirestore } = require("firebase-admin/firestore")
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require('google-spreadsheet');

initializeApp();

exports.testeadm = functions.https.onRequest(async(req, res) => {
    console.log("teste")
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet("...")
    await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({"private_key": "...",
    "client_email": "..."});
    await doc.loadInfo();
    console.log(doc.title)
    })
```

This is the register Firebase log error message:

```
testeadm
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":3,"message":"Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation."},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"..."},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","resourceName":"projects/.../locations/us-central1/functions/testeadm"}
```

Comment: What is your node version?

Comment: But in my pachage.json:
"engines": {
    "node": "12"
  }

Comment: Update it to 14 and try once. It can be an issue with the minimum required dependencies with the node.

Comment: It didn't work
i  functions: updating Node.js 14 function testeadm(us-central1)...

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        testeadm(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

Error: There was an error deploying functions

Comment: Are you using Blaze plan for your project ?

Comment: For this project i´m using Blaze plan

Comment: Okay, You should try connecting firebase support. They will resolve this or give solution.